# Shell script to login to remote VM and run commands from remote VM

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I need to login to a remote VM and run some commands. I am able to login successfully but echo command does not return list of files from the remote VM instead it returns output from local machine. Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

```
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<EOF
cd /var;
echo "$(ls)";
EOF
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after removing echo. PFB solution:

```
    ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1 << EOT
    cd /var;
    ls -ltr;
    EOT
    exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `$` in `EOF` sequence like this:

```
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<EOF
cd /var;
echo "\$(ls)";
EOF
```

Or escape whole EOF sequence like this:

```
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<'EOF'
cd /var;
echo "$(ls)";
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, if you quote the marker, then substitution doesn't take place in the local shell:

```
ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1<<'EOF'
cd /var;
echo "$(ls)";
EOF
exit
```